# How can I shorten this multiple assignment in Lua?

Tags: code-golf, tips, lua

Is there any better way to golf this (other than removing newlines/indentation)?

```lua
function(a,b,...)
  local c=s(a,b)
  local d=c
  for i,v in ipairs{...} do d=d:push(v) end
  return c
end
```

I'm particularly bothered by the double `local` usage, but as Lua does not have multiple assignment, and I cannot [use function parameters to declare the locals](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39175811/405017), I can't see a way to remove them.

*For those who care, this is the implementation of the `__call` metamethod in my quick hack of a linked-list ~class used in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4910622/405017).*

Comment: Lua does have multiple assignment: https://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/manual.html#2.4.3

Comment: That's parallel, assignment, though. See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10842679/405017). You cannot use it to share values.

Comment: Could you perhaps declare both variables in the same line and then do assignment later? Like `local c,d=s({v=b},a),0` `d=c`? That takes out one of the `local` keywords. I don't know anything about Lua, though.

Comment: Yes that can be done.

Comment: @ValueInk Post that as an answer! Note that you don't need the `,0`.

Comment: Does `s` have side effects? If not I guess you could do `local c,d=s(a,b),s(a,b)`.

Comment: @feersum Good question. Yes, `s()` creates a table and returns it. The shared value is a reference to an element, not a simple value.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As requested in the comments, here it is as an answer.

```lua
local c,d=s(a,b)  -- d is nil
d=c
```

This saves you one `local` declaration, should give you -5 bytes.